# How to attach the screenshot for every step in extent report?

Tags: selenium, screenshot, hybrid, extentreports

For example,
I have 4 pages in my application, here I want to attach the screenshot after every step to the extent report in hybrid framework.

Expected behavior:- I am expecting screenshot should get attached at each step.

Current behavior:- Screenshot getting attached at the bottom aligning in a single line
Please let me know if it is possible

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please post the code what you have tried.